# Deleting a "value" from a multimap

Tags: c++, stl, multimap

My requirement is to delete a a "value" from the multimap and not the "key".
A key may have multiple values and `i` want delete a specific value.My requirement is similar to deleting a node from a linked list.

I am doing so by using `multimap::erase()` method.
But after deletion if I try to print the values of the multimap, the values deleted using `multimap::erase()` are also printed.

below is my code snippet:

```
void Clientqueues::clearSubscription(string name,string sessionid)
{
    pair<multimap<string,string>::iterator,multimap<string,string>::iterator> i;
    multimap<string, string>::iterator j;
    i = registeredClientInfo.equal_range(name);

    if (j == registeredClientInfo.end())
            return;
    for(j=i.first;j != i.second;++j)
    {
        if((j->second) == sessionid) registeredClientInfo.erase(j->second);
    }

    for(j=i.first;j != i.second;++j)
    {
        cout<<""<<j->second<<endl;///This prints the erased values too;
    }

}
```

Am i doing something wrong?
Any help in this regard greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most important, you call `erase(j->second)`, when you meant to call `erase(j)`. You're not erasing the element of the multimap pointed to by `j`, you're erasing all elements whose keys are equal to the value of the element pointed to by `j` (which is `sessionid`). I expect that's nothing.

Also: call `equal_range` again after the `erase` loop is complete - the effect of using an erased iterator is undefined, so if you erased the first iterator `i.first`, then you can't start iterating from there again afterwards.

Note that this also means there's a bug in your loop that does the `erase`, since in the case that you do call `erase`, you increment `j` when it holds an iterator value that's no longer valid. Unfortunately, the correct code is:

```
for(j=i.first;j != i.second;)
{
    if((j->second) == sessionid) {
        auto next = j;
        ++next;
        registeredClientInfo.erase(j);
        j = next;
    } else {
        ++j;
    }
}
```

Or if you prefer:

```
for(j=i.first;j != i.second;)
{
    auto current = j;
    ++j;
    if((current->second) == sessionid) registeredClientInfo.erase(current);
}
```

Or if the entry is unique for the key/value pair, so that you only have to remove at most one thing, then:

```
for(j=i.first;j != i.second;++j)
{
    if((j->second) == sessionid) {
        registeredClientInfo.erase(j);
        break;
    }
}
```

`if (j == registeredClientInfo.end()) return;` isn't right either, since `j` is uninitialized when you do it. If the key isn't found, then `equal_range` returns an empty range (two equal iterator values), so your other loops will do nothing anyway.

Comment: I'm having an issue with this answer, what happens if you have only one element at the specified key ? It seems the range points to the only element it found and thuse i.first == i.second, and the element won't get deleted by the for loop...

Comment: @Tab: if there's one element in the range then `first` and `second` aren't equal. They're equal if there's no elements at all in the range.

Answer (score 0):

If you deleted `i.first` or `i.second` the iterators get invalidated implying undefined behavior.